# Set values on TableView Swift 3 on function

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview, alamofire

Actually, I need set data on my TableView, the strings that I get are on a function that makes a POST Request on a WebService.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    names.append("Data 1")
    names.append("Data 2")
    names.append("Data 3")
    self.request()
    MyTable.delegate = self
    MyTable.dataSource = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

On `self.request()` function I have a post request that works fine:

```
func request(){

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "action": "*",
        "key":"*": "*"
    ]
    Alamofire.request("my_url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            print("Validation Successful")
            print(response.result.value)
            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            let userId = response.object(forKey: "Data")!
            let data = userId as! NSArray
            for item in data { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                print("Obj: \"\(obj["KeyName"] as! String)\"")
                self.names.append(obj["KeyName"] as! String)
            }
            print(userId)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The first part works fine:

```
names.append("imac")
names.append("Macbook")
names.append("iphon")
```

And `print("Obj: \"\(obj["KeyName"] as! String)\"")` shows me on the console the strings, but when I set it on the TableView,  `self.names.append(obj["KeyName"] as! String)` doesn't show the data only the first part, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess that's because it's asynchronous. So you need to do `MyTable.reloadData()` once you get the new names. Also avoid naming var starting with an uppercase (like `MyTable` => `myTable`).

Comment: Thanks that was the issue, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update data to the datasource, you will have to reload your tableView to display the new content. After the for loop add the table reload and it should update the tableView. Since your Alamofire call is executed asynchronously in a different thread (other than the main thread), update the tableView in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  
    MyTable.reloadData()  
})
```

In your example:

```
func request(){

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "action": "*",
        "key":"*": "*"
    ]
    Alamofire.request("my_url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            print("Validation Successful")
            print(response.result.value)
            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            let userId = response.object(forKey: "Data")!
            let data = userId as! NSArray
            for item in data { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                print("Obj: \"\(obj["KeyName"] as! String)\"")
                self.names.append(obj["KeyName"] as! String)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  
                MyTable.reloadData()  
            })

            print(userId)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If an answer helped to resolve your issue, you can mark it to be the answer/ upvote it.